# I need some help trying to understand how to loop back to the start of a function and keep the changes that were made when it returns in python

Tags: python-3.x

there's more to the code but this is the basis of what im struggling with. This is all for a varsity project.

```
def myFunc():


    
        SA = 1
        def myFunc(SA):
     
             while True:

                  print(" \n 1.Statistics \n 2.Prevention \n 3.Symptoms \n 4.Treatment \n 5.Report case \n 6.Exit \n")

                  userInput = input("Enter a choice(1/2/3/4/5/6): ")

                  if userInput == "1":
                  #when the user chooses 5 and it returns to the top of the function it needs to carry over the += 1 when it returns back to userInput.
                      print("\nCurrently in SA there are " + str(SA) + " Confirmed cases \nCurrently in USA there are " + str(USA) + " Confirmed cases \nCurrently in China there are " + str(China) + " Confirmed cases\n")
```

This is where the function needs to add one everytime the user inputs "y" twice in the prompt

```
                  if userInput == "5":

                       input2 = input("Do you have any of the symptoms? enter y/n: ")

                       if input2 == "n":
                         print("You do not have COVID")
                       elif input2 == "y":
                            input3 = input("Is your temperature above 38.5°C? Enter y/n: ")
                            if input3 == "n":
                               print("You do not have COVID")
                            elif input3 == "y":
                               print("In which country are you select an option below \n1.SA \n2.USA \n3.China")
                               input4 = input("Enter an option (1/2/3): ")

                             #This needs to add 1 to the variable "SA" when I return back to the beggining of the function.
                                if input4 == "1":
                                    print("You have COVID-19 please see treatment")
                                    SA += 1
                                    return myFunc(SA)

                              #This needs to add 1 to the variable "USA" when I return back to the beggining of the function.
                                 elif input4 == "2":
                                     print("You have COVID-19 please see treatment")

                    #This needs to add 1 to the variable "China" when I return back to the beggining of the function.  
                                  elif input4 == "3":
                                      print("You have COVID-19 please see treatment")
```

I'm really confused, should this all even be in a function in the first place. If you need more information ill be happy to provide. I'm still somewhat new to coding and python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simplified example

```py
def myFunc(SA):

    while True:
        a = input('>enter')
        if a=='1':
            print(SA)
            SA += 1
            return myFunc(SA)


myFunc(1)
```

Comment: Sorry i fixed it now

Comment: is there a way to take it out of the loop?

Comment: like this?:

   def myFunc():

         SA = 1
         USA = 1
         China = 1

         while True:

Comment: yes, so long as they are on separate lines.

Comment: it seems to not keep the + 1 if i use the variable inside the while true, should I be using return myFunc() after SA += 1 or can i use something else?

Comment: its doing the same thing i dont know how to include my code in a formatted way like you did

Comment: the return myFunc() implements recursion and so will reset everything.

Comment: what can i use to return the user back to the "userInput" function after they finished with choice 5?